# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' when executing a TimerTrigger

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

Function name(s) (as appropriate): TimerTrigger
Core Tools version: 3.0.3388
Runtime version 3.0.15417.0
Operating System:  Linux
Language:  Python 3.8

```
# requirements.txt
azure-functions==1.6.0
requests==2.25.1
```

To reproduce the problem, I created a TimerTrigger function using the TimerTrigger template. The only modification I made to the code generated by the template was to add an import statement for the requests module.

```py
#__init__.py

import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import requests

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

The function works fine locally and displays the expected output.  However, the deployed function does not.  From the logs viewed in Azure Portal, The requests module is not installed even though it is specified in requirements.txt. Here is the function log, viewed using Azure Portal:

Result:

```
Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'. 
Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound 
Stack: 
    File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 288, in _handle__function_load_request func_request.metadata.entry_point) 
    File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 42, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) 
    File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) 
    File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 76, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) 
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/init.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
    File "/home/site/wwwroot/TimerTrigger/init.py", line 5, in import requests
```

Comment: [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode#view-project-files). Can you see package installed in `.python_packages/lib/python3.6/site-packages/<package-name>` or `.python_packages/lib/site-packages/<package-name>`? Also can you include command that you use to deploy your code? Can you also get logs from host startup and see if there are any errors (`traces | operation_Name == ""` in App Insights if you're using that)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I used the information you provided and did not reproduce your problem. It worked well on my side. Could you please tell me what method you use to deploy your function?

Comment: @Kashyap and Frank Gong.  Thank you for your input!  The link you provided to view project files was very helpful.  My problem seems to be related to the Function App (that was just created) I am trying to deploy to.  I was able to deploy to a previously defined Function App and the function worked!  I am looking into what the differences there are between the two Function Apps.